# Parsing HTML of thesaurus.com to get the synonyms of word in android

Tags: android, jsoup

I am trying to sparse the data from https://www.thesaurus.com/ HTML to get synonyms of and word,

[image]

Here I identified the u1 tag class as used to get the list in "li" tag as highlighted in the above image
I want to parse the list in the u1 tag, so I used it in the doc.select as in below code

```
String url = "https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/hell";

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            Elements data = doc.select("u1.css-17d6qyx-WordGridLayoutBox et6tpn80");
            int size = data.size();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "doc: "+doc);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "data: "+data);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "size"+size);
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {


                String synonym = data.select("span.css-1y6i96q-WordGridItemBox etbu2a32")
                        .select("a")
                        .eq(i)
                        .attr("href");

                parseItems.add(new ParseItem(synonym));
                Log.d("items", " synonym: " + synonym);
```

Below is the result I got,

```
2020-07-08 14:22:52.561 16508-16576/com.example.scraping_synonyms D/MainActivity: doc: <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
     <head> 
      <meta charSet="utf-8"> 
      <title>Hell Synonyms, Hell Antonyms | Thesaurus.com</title> 
      <meta name="description" content="Synonyms for hell at Thesaurus.com with free online thesaurus, antonyms, and definitions. Find descriptive alternatives for hell. "> 
      <meta property="og:title" content="Synonyms of hell | Thesaurus.com"> 
      <meta property="og:description" content="Synonyms for hell from Thesaurus.com, the world’s leading online source for synonyms, antonyms, and more."> 
      <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.thesaurus.com/assets/thesaurus_social_logo-4b42f0643b92eaf85fc0e4e78aa84a8d.png"> 
      <meta property="og:site_name" content="www.thesaurus.com"> 
      <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary"> 
      <meta property="twitter:site" content="@Dictionarycom"> 
      <meta property="fb:app_id" content="118269238218175">
      <meta property="fb:admins" content="100000304287730,109125464873"> 
      <meta name="msvalidate.01" content="DF5542D7723770377E9ABFF59AC1DC97"> 
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://www.thesaurus.com/assets/favicon-54545f5303fccb956af394ac10f1655d.png"> 
      <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/hell"> 
      <link rel="preload" href="https://www.thesaurus.com/assets/dictionary-font-bdb88a42d7d4dd71d0a4be54bda1f59a.woff" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
      <link rel="preconnect" href="//ads.pubmatic.com" crossorigin>
      <link rel="preconnect" href="//securepubads.g.doubleclick.net" crossorigin>
      <link rel="preconnect" href="//cm.g.doubleclick.net" crossorigin>
      <link rel="preconnect" href="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com" crossorigin>
      <link rel="preconnect" href="//ib.adnxs.com" crossorigin>
      <link rel="preconnect" href="//ce.lijit.com" crossorigin>
      <link rel="preconnect" href="//ap.lijit.com" crossorigin>
      <link rel="preconnect" href="//us-u.openx.net" crossorigin> 
      <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fastlane.rubiconproject.com">
      <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//pixel.rubiconproject.com">
      <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//token.rubiconproject.com">
      <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//dsum-sec.casalemedia.com">
      <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//as-sec.casalemedia.com">
      <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//gum.criteo.com">
      <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//static.criteo.net">
      <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//bidder.criteo.com">
      <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//adserver.adtech.advertising.com">
      <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//cdata.carambo.la"> 
      <script>
    !function(n,e){var t,o,i,c=[],f={passive:!0,capture:!0},r=new Date,a="pointerup",u="pointercancel";function p(n,c){t||(t=c,o=n,i=new Date,w(e),s())}function s(){o>=0&&o<i-r&&(c.forEach(function(n){n(o,t)}),c=[])}function l(t){if(t.cancelable){var o=(t.timeStamp>1e12?new Date:performance.now())-t.timeStamp;"pointerdown"==t.type?function(t,o){function i(){p(t,o),r()}function c(){r()}function r(){e(a,i,f),e(u,c,f)}n(a,i,f),n(u,c,f)}(o,t):p(o,t)}}function w(n){["click","mousedown","keydown","touchstart","pointerdown"].forEach(function(e){n(e,l,f)})}w(n),self.perfMetrics=self.perfMetrics||{},self.perfMetrics.onFirstInputDelay=function(n){c.push(n),s()}}(addEventListener,removeEventListener);
    perfMetrics.onFirstInputDelay(function(delay, evt) {
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        dataLayer.push({
            event: 'FID',
            action: evt.type,
            value: delay
        });
    });
    </script> 
      <script defer src="https://www.thesaurus.com/assets/client-4e944b31.js"></script>
      <script defer src="https://www.thesaurus.com/assets/react-456bf542.js"></script>
      <script defer src="https://www.thesaurus.com/assets/vendor~253ae210-5a6e2153.js"></script>
      <script defer src="https://www.thesaurus.com/assets/vendor~7274e1de-00d240c3.js"></script>
      <script defer src="https://www.thesaurus.com/assets/vendor~7d359b94-5bc2d791.js"></script>
      <script defer src="https://www.thesaurus.com/assets/vendor~b9cf3951-fea1f433.js"></script> 
      <!-- Ad integration with callbac
2020-07-08 14:22:52.562 16508-16576/com.example.scraping_synonyms D/MainActivity: data: 
2020-07-08 14:22:52.562 16508-16576/com.example.scraping_synonyms D/MainActivity: size0
```

I am new at this data scraping from jsoup. Could anyone explain what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the CSS class for the elements you want to extract, it is easily done with `getElementsByClass`:

```java
        Elements data = doc.getElementsByClass("etbu2a31");
        //here we have a collection of all the elements that have etbu2a31 class on them
        for (Element e: data){
            System.out.println(" synonym URL: " + e.attr("href"));
            System.out.println(" synonym text: " + e.text());
        }
```